# Set mmc2 on beaglebone black

Tags: beagleboneblack

I am working with a Beaglebone Black and I would like to use the mmc2 slot.

according to AM335xx TRM, a beaglebone black should have 3 mmc available:
 mmc0 (sd card);
mmc1 (2G flash),
 mmc2.

I am trying to enable mmc2 by device tree (and I am quite sure to have the right pin settings) but, by doing
dmesg
I obtain:

```
/ocp/mmc@47810000: can't find DMA channel
 omap_hsmmc mmc.11: unable to obtain RX DMA engine channel 65
```

By putting the oscilloscope probe on the header (e.g. the mmc2 clk signal), I do not see any transition.
I already removed R 160 to have mmc2 cmd accessible but I do not see any transition also there.

I tried both to enable it by

```
 echo > /sys/devices/..../slots
```

and by

```
  capemgr.enable_partno
```

with no success:
I can see it in

```
/sys/devices/..../slots
```

(with the L meaning loaded)..but no way to see any signal on the header.

I already googled it but answers are not clear at all.
Any ideas?

My

```
 uname -a
```

is:

```
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13 #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 02:11:09 EDT 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you found solution yet? I'm planning to use BeagleBoard Black for my project and I also want to use 3rd MMC. Internal 2GB flash for OS, micorSD for logs, and mmc2 for read only data.

Comment: No, no solution..I just decided to not use another SD card.

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure the mmc2 DMA events to some DMA channel since these events are not direct mapped.

I was not able to do this successfully using device tree overlays. So I made a change in the 
am335-x-bone-common.dtsi directly (not sure this is the best way though):

```
&edma {
ti,edma-xbar-event-map = <32 12>,   /* gpevt2 -> 12 */
                         <30 20>,   /* xdma_event_intr2 -> 20 */
+                        <1  32>,
+                        <2  33>;   
};
```

In the example above the event 1 (SDTXEVT2) was mapped to channel 32 and event 2 (SDRXEVT2) to channel 33.

In case you want to pick another open DMA channel check tables 11-23. Direct Mapped and Table 11-24. Crossbar Mapped from the technical reference manual Rev J.

In your device tree overlay file add these channels in the mmc3 node:

```
dmas = <&edma 32 
        &edma 33>;
dma-names = "tx", "rx";
```